# Sql dictionary and spell check

Tags: sql

Where can i download a free english dictionary and what would be the best way in PHP to spell check against the words in the dictionary? Is there a better way to save the dictionary in SQL? Here is what i am looking to do:
I have a textbox: 
In this textbox user can only enter one word only... I want to check if this word entered is an english word or not?
Is 
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page
a right place to download dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You can find dictionaries here: ftp://ftp.openwall.com/pub/wordlists/languages/English/ (for English)

If you want to do this in SQL, you can load this data into table with index on this field and then check if this record exists.